# on click header menu call all subcategory

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have create four EZ pages on zen cart (furniture, kilim, pillow,rugs) which is display on header and also create four category (furniture, kilim, pillow, rugs) and also create sub category to all category.

When I click furniture (Header Menu) then show furniture related all sub category on left side box.

Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for creating a horizontal dropdown menu.

http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=323